¿Cómo mostrar una nueva pantalla en Winforms sin cambiar de ventana?
estoy haciendo un programa en Winforms y me gustaría saber si se puede cambiar el formulario sin tener que abrir una nueva pestaña.
Ej. de lo que digo: Tengo un formulario con varios botones que me llevan a otros formularios pero yo querría que cambiase ese primer formulario
para que no me pete el ordenador con tantos formularios abiertos.
Aquí os dejo el código del formulario del que hablo primero:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MineGuide
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Colección_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Colección ventana = new Colección())
            {
                ventana.ShowDialog();
            }
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}



Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! yo te diria que si a todo, pero tu pregunta es tan rara que no se que contestar...

A que te refieres con "abrir nueva pestaña"

Hola, muchas gracias por responder (A los dos!!) me refería a abrir una nueva colección de elementos en un mismo formulario. Pero ya encontré como hacerlo (Hay que usar, por ejemplo, un  tab control). Muchas gracias de todas formas.
